# How long do we have to be in range of another 3DS for Streetpass to trigger?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, streetpass

How long do 2 3DSs have to be "in range" to download each other's information?

I was wondering this as I was driving in a car; will driving through the range of a 3DS for about 10 seconds be enough to download Street Pass information? What about a bike being in range for 20 seconds?

Comment: About 30 meters is the range. Source: http://techforums.nintendo.com/thread/14814

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wireless communication speed depends on many factors, not just distance, but also what's between the two things. A car is generally not a great thing to try to send signals through; a messenger bag on a bike is not much more difficult than air.

Streetpass also transmits a variable amount of data. If you have no games aside from Streetpass Plaza, it will finish faster than if you have to transmit information about several games. (I don't know if Streetpass can do a "partial" transmit - sending and updating each game individually.)

In ideal circumstances, 10 seconds is more than enough time. I have seen a Streetpass happen 2-3 seconds after closing my 3DS, if my wife's 3DS is also suspended and in the same room.

Comment: The "partial" transfer your referring is a true thing, I've had a game, street fighter 4, get a tag but not my plaza. And it was while driving so there is that, but generally speaking walking around is the best scenario to get a full pass.

Comment: I can confirm that StreetPasses can occur while driving.  I do make a habit of setting the 3DS in a tray on the dashboard, so that it's raised to the level of the car windows.

Comment: I once got a SpotPass in a parking lot while my 3DS was either in my pocket or my messenger bag.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had it work while driving to my knowledge. But maybe I've just never been in range of a person. I only get a few passes per week in general so our area doesn't have a lot of people.
I would think its possible, I had a game called Treasure World which worked based off of wireless internet signals, and that thing would collect like crazy while driving.